# Passar valor de uma página para input de outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

eu tenho uma página html onde o usuário digita o email e eu realizo a verificação. Caso aquele email não esteja no banco de dados, é um novo usuário e portanto, redireciono para a página de cadastro.

Na página de cadastro quero que o campo email venha já com o email digitado na página anterior. Como faço?

página 1

```
 <label id=id_email name="email"> </label>
```

página 2

```
   <label id=id_email name="email"> </label>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
           $("#id_email").val("bianca@bianca.com");
 });
```

Comment: Manda por sessão ou querystring.

Comment: A ideia é mandar por sessão mesmo, mas não sei como fazer, estou aprendendo

Comment: Que linguagem está utilizando?

Comment: Python usando Django

Comment: Não sei nem uma linha de Python. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `sessionStorage`, dessa forma o navegador vai salvar uma `sessão` com seus dados e você pode recuperar em qualquer pagina.

**Pagina 1**

```
<input type="text" id="email">
<script>
    let valor = document.getElementById('email').value
    sessionStorage.setItem('email', valor)
</script>
```

**Pagina 2**

```
<input type="text" id="RecuperaEmail">

<script>
    document.getElementById('RecuperaEmail').value = sessionStorage.email
</script>
```

Ou pode fazer isso com `jQuery`

**Pagina 1**

```
<input type="text" id="email">
<script>
    var valor = $('#email').val()
    sessionStorage.setItem('email', valor)
</script>
```

**Pagina 2**

```
<input type="text" id="RecuperaEmail">

<script>
    $('#RecuperaEmail').val(sessionStorage.email)
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigada Rafael, consegui resolver!

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar da seguinte forma.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="volposition" value="{{ request.REQUEST.email }}">
```

Levando em conta que você faz na action o post pra enviar a outra pagina.